# default argument cause cannot read property of undefined?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
export const getNotifications = (
  role,
  page,
  { see_more = undefined }
) => async dispatch => {

}
```

I got error of `TypeError: Cannot read property 'see_more' of undefined`, but isn't I already set the default value is undefined? Why there's still the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use it as a varible paramater, not as a object:

```
export const getNotifications = (
   role,
   page,
   see_more = undefined
) => async dispatch => {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I bet this is happening when you do this:

```js
blah.getNotifications('admin', 5); // and you didn't put anything for see_more
```

Actually JS is telling you exactly what is happening under the hood, and it is not a bug. To fix that do this little trick I learnt when trying to achieve this with as little code as possible like you are trying to do:

```js
export const getNotifications = (
  role,
  page,
  { see_more = undefined } = {}
) => async dispatch => {

}
```

That little `= {}` in front of the `{ see_more = undefined }` parameter is all you need; welcome to advanced JS.

You see, JS is trying to destructure an undefined object; yes `{ see_more = undefined }` is being treated as a parameter on its own before the destructuring. I figured JS is seeing: `blah.getNotifications('admin', 5, undefined);`. So that param is `undefined` and it fails when it tries to destructure it. The trick here is to give a default for the parameter itself before the destructuring step so that you get: `blah.getNotifications('admin', 5, {});` when nothing was given for that param. Which is then followed by the destructuring that fills in the defaults you gave.

Funny things is I figured also that that default can actually contain other defaults when there was totally nothing defined for the param. Though `{}` is enough to work with your normal defaults, you can actually go hacky by doing the following eg:

```js
export const getNotifications = (
  role,
  page,
  { see_more = 'more text', another = 'foo', gumbo = 'mukombo' } = {another: 'bar', gumbo: 'why didnt you put anything'}
) => async dispatch => {

}
```

so you will get:

```js
see_more === 'more text', another === 'bar', gumbo === 'why didnt you put anything'
```

if you called with:

```js
blah.getNotifications('admin', 5);
```

but if you call with at least one of the properties eg:

```js
blah.getNotifications('admin', 5, {another: 'dzetse'} );
```

you get:

```js
see_more === 'more text', another === 'dzetse', gumbo === 'mukombo'
```

Here you are getting other partial defaults (both objs are used to get 1 final object that is then destructured) when there was totally nothing (`undefined`).

Just wish they can just accept that simple erroneous syntax as well.